# Mockito when()....thenReturn() always returning null

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework, mockito

I'm currently writing tests for a Play Controller.

In my controller I have some service that calls a method

```
MyMethod {
   String test = myService.test()
   ObjectNode result = myService.myFunc(..someListOfEnums, ...string, ...someListOfString, ...someString, ...some String, ...clientObject)
}
```

When running my tests with the mocked `myService`, with a when()...thenReturn() for `myFunc(...)` the result is always null. When I do the same with `test()` the test string is always populated. Here the `MyService.class` is an interface.

In my test I am doing:

```
Client _someMockedObject = mock(Client.class);
MyService _myService = mock(MyService.class);

ObjectNode n = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
n.set(Constants.RESULT_FIELD, JsonNodeFactory.instance.arrayNode());

List<SomeEnumClass> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Constants.Enum.test, Constants.Enum.test2));

String test = "test";
List<String> c = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("test1", "test2"));
String test2 = "";
String test3 = "";

when(_myService.test()).thenReturn("hello"); <--- FIRST
when(_myService.myFunc(l, test, c, test2, test3, _someMockedObject)).thenReturn(n); <--- SECOND

PrestoResource myController = new myResource(_someMockedObject, _myService);
Result result = myController.myMethod("");

...
```

Looks like I"m using the when and thenReturn correctly but am I not putting in the right parameters into the second method?

Comment: Probably some of the arguments to myFunc in test are not equal to actual arguments to myFunc in method under test. Make sure they are equal, or use ArgumentMatchers.

Comment: Is there anyway I can create anyList of Enums?

Comment: @Lesiak I"m also wondering if passing in a mocked object (in this case the `_someMockedObject`) to myFunc will affect it?

Comment: 1. Are you asking about https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyList-- 2. I think mock objects are equal to themselves (that is they use Object.equals for equality) I suggest you use a debugger and check for equality with expected arguments.

Comment: 2. I'm not sure what I"m checking for in terms of the expected arguments. I know that `_someMockedObject` is mocked by Mockito. Am I checking whether or not `_someMockedObject` is equal to a `Client`? I'm just a little bit unclear here.

Comment: I meant all arguments, not only the mocked client.

Comment: Isn't the mocked object guaranteed to be whatever `Client` is? Or it would fail straight up there anyways. For the other ones I could see maybe that could be the case..